# How to get project namespace name using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am creating class library file. In this I embedded stored procedure script file. so I need to take sp data as a string and I have to create in c#. so for this GetManifestResourceStream method need full-name of assemble and script file. so I did . But I did not figure out why my stream object getting null value.

```
string strNameSpace = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream(strNameSpace + "GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql")) 
{
  // Here stream  is null.

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider to add question to the body of the post and describe what is your actual goal (getting a resource by a name does not sound like a good final goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sort of strange to get constant string value by getting assembly name... But you are missing "." in the way to construct the name:

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream(strNameSpace + ".GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql"))
```

It will likely be safe and easier to simply hardcode the name:

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream("WhateverYoourNamespaceIs.GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql"))
```

Note "How to embed and access resources" is available on [Micorsoft support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) and covers this topic.